# How to call partial view in script section

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new in MVC. I have a button when i click it should go to a partial view and return data i need. I do not know how should i achieve that:

Main view:

```
<script>

if ($("#btnFilter").click(function () {

  @{Html.RenderPartial("partialView"); }

 }));
</script>
```

partial view

```
var dtDrpVals = new selectedDateDrpdnVal();
debugger;
$.ajax({

    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("controller","Dashbrd")",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "regionalManager": dtDrpVals.drpValue, "dtFrom": dtDrpVals.fromDate, "dtTo": dtDrpVals.toDate }),
    success: function (result) {
    }
});
```

Comment: does your partial view do anything else other than make an ajax call? If not then just get your button click event to make the ajax call. This isn't really what partial views are for - they should just return some HTML generated from Razor code. If you've got some re-usable JS code then put it in a .js code and use a `<script>` tag to include it in your page. If you want to execute that code at a certain time, wrap it in a function which you can call when you need it.

Comment: @ADyson in my view when i click on the button it shows many things,different information,different charts and grids,having them all in a single view just creating a nightmare for me,i thought with partial view i cant separate them but any other solution?

Comment: of course you can use partials for the HTML of the components, but not for script. And also that's not how you call a partial from JS either, you need to make an ajax call to get the HTML dynamically when the button is clicked.

Comment: @ADyson ajax call should be in my main view ?or in partial?

Comment: in the main view, when the button is clicked, instead of the Razor call to RenderPartial (which will have just statically placed some stuff which the browser probably thinks is HTML). You can't include JS in a partial view...it won't get executed.

Comment: @ADyson please write a sample using my code,when i click the button how should my partial view works

Comment: well it's not even clear if you should be using a partial at all. According to your question the partial view contains nothing but Javascript. I've already told you that Javascript snippets should be included using .js files. Partial Views are for returning server-generated HTML, but you don't seem to have any.

Comment: @ADyson you mean instead of partial view,should i use diffrent javascript files and use them in my view,imagine i have diffrent charts diffrent grids and diffrent buttons,i should create diffrent js files for them and feeding them by ajax call in my view,right?

Comment: well I don't know really what all these things are, but probably something like that. Think of it like when you have a 3rd-party component library such as DataTables or something like that which uses Javascript to generate some HTML: it's included as a separate JS file...then you call a function when you want to use it. So if you have some of your JS code which is used to create a grid, then put it in a separate JS file, and have a function which is used to call it and pass some configuration and/or data into it, and then generate the result. You can call that function whenever you like

Comment: That's how all web applications work, nothing specific to MVC at all in fact. I don't know where you got the idea from to use a Partial View for that. However if the HTML of your grids/charts etc are generated using _server-side_ code (i.e. C#/Razor) then that's when you might decide to use a Partial View.

Answer (score 3):

In the html define a div where you want the partial to be located in and in the ajax success put the result of the call to the controller into that div, assuming you are returning a partialview:

```
$("#The id of the div").html(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is Make an Action in your ASP.NET controller that returns a Partial View and in your jquery, you should make an AJAX call to that action with required parameters that eventually will return a Partial View to your Jquery, and the data you will receive from your action will be of type **'HTML'** and not JSON.

once you receive HTML data in your success function of AJAX call you can replace it with any Div.